# Enabling MCP251xD on SPI4 on the Rpi4

Tags: pi-4, can-bus, dtoverlay

We have a hardware in which the MCP2518FD is connected to the SPI4 of the Raspberry Pi 4.It appears that the existing driver allows for SPI0 and SPI configurations only. Please guide how to configure the driver for the SPI4. I understand that I will need to recompile the MCP251xFD.dts file but I don't know exactly what to modify.